# JSF <h:commandButton> with <f:ajax> not executed on @ViewScoped bean but <a4j:ajax> works

Tags: ajax, jsf, button, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a Facelets subview at `/subviews/document-tree.xhtml` that renders a tree for each tab on a `<rich:tabPanel>` client. The page and sub views are based on JSF 2 and RichFaces 4.

```
<ui:composition ...>
  <rich:tree value="#{rootNode}" var="treeNode" id="#{treeId}">

    <rich:treeNode ... id="chapternode">

      <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <rich:outputText value="#{treeNode.name}" />
        <h:commandLink>
          <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="delete.png"  />
          <rich:componentControl target="remove-chapter-popup" operation="show" />
        </h:commandLink>
        <rich:popupPanel modal="true"
                         onmaskclick="#{rich:component('remove-chapter-popup')}.hide(); return false;"
                         id="remove-chapter-popup">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Remove chapter?" />
          </f:facet>
          <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:outputText value="X" />
          </f:facet>
          <p>Remove chapter #{treeNode.name}?</p>
          <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:commandButton value="Add"
                             action="#{nodeManager.removeChapterNode(treeNode)}" 
                             onclick="#{rich:component('remove-chapter-popup')}.hide(); return true;">

              <!--f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" /-->        <!-- never executed! -->
              <a4j:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" />           <!-- this works however! -->

            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value="Cancel"
                             onclick="#{rich:component('remove-chapter-popup')}.hide(); return false;" immediate="true" />
          </h:panelGrid>
        </rich:popupPanel>
      </h:panelGrid>

    </rich:treeNode>

    ...

  </rich:tree>
</ui:composition>
```

This basically shows tree nodes with their name plus an image  to the right for deletion.

Each tree sub view is placed into a `<rich:tab>`, so the tab panel **does** have the required enclosing `<h:form>`. There are no other nested forms (forbidden anyway).

The `#{nodeManager.removeChapterNode(treeNode)}` bean was correctly marked as `@ViewScoped`.

Now what happens is kinda strange:

When using `<f:ajax execute="@this" ... />` the button *never* executes, whereas using `<a4j:ajax execute="@this" ... />` *always* works.

**Why? What's wrong here?**

It doesn't make much sense, given the fact that RichFaces `<a4j:ajax>` is based 100% on JSF 2 `<f:ajax>` according to their own words.

*Could it be a bug in JSF 2.1.7*, which I'm using? (the implementation that came with JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final)

Comment: Do they generate different HTML markup?

Comment: Yes, slightly different code, but obviously that's part of this problem. See answer. The question remains if JSF should be able to handle id's with spaces...?

Comment: Spaces are illegal in IDs. I wonder why it didn't threw `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I thought so, but I had the same question as you. Is it a JSF bug then? This should be fixed in JSF 2 IMHO (even more importantly than RichFaces).

Comment: It's not a bug in Mojarra. It already validates the `setId()` as per the javadoc.

Comment: Why did you wonder why "it" didn't throw an IAE then? Do you mean because JSF is doing nothing this is the specified behavior of that illegal ID?

Comment: Oh I meant the `TreeNodeImpl#addChild()`.

Comment: `TreeNodeImpl` keys are of type `Object`, don't know what RF does to generate HTML IDs from those when the tree is rendered. I'll need to ask the RF guys for this.

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12245

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the reduced diff:

```
<form id="tree-form" name="tree-form" method="post" action="/pqgenerator2/debug.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
 ...
  <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
- <td><input id="tree-form:sorting-tree-one:real root:j_idt34" type="submit" name="tree-form:sorting-tree-one:real root:j_idt34" value="Fortfahren" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'RichFaces.$(\'tree-form:sorting-tree-one:real root:add-root-chapter-popup\').hide(); return true;','mojarra.ab(this,event,\'action\',\'@this tree-form:sorting-tree-one:real root:new-root-chapter-name-input\',\'@form\')');return false" /></td>
+ <td><input id="tree-form:sorting-tree-one:real root:j_idt34" type="submit" name="tree-form:sorting-tree-one:real root:j_idt34" value="Fortfahren" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'RichFaces.$(\'tree-form:sorting-tree-one:real root:add-root-chapter-popup\').hide(); return true;','RichFaces.ajax(this,event,{&quot;parameters&quot;:{&quot;javax.faces.behavior.event&quot;:&quot;action&quot;,&quot;org.richfaces.ajax.component&quot;:&quot;tree\\u002Dform:sorting\\u002Dtree\\u002Done:real root:j_idt34&quot;} ,&quot;sourceId&quot;:this} )');return false" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
...

- </div></span></span></div></div><input type="hidden" name="tree-form:sorting-tree-one__SELECTION_STATE" id="tree-form:sorting-tree-one__SELECTION_STATE" class="rf-tr-sel-inp" value="" /><script type="text/javascript">new RichFaces.ui.Tree("tree\u002Dform:sorting\u002Dtree\u002Done",{"toggleType":"client"} );</script></div></div><script type="text/javascript">new RichFaces.ui.Tab("tree\u002Dform:j_idt21",{"index":0,"leave":null,"togglePanelId":"tree\u002Dform:tree\u002Dtabpanel","switchMode":"client","name":"Blah GmbH","enter":null,"disabled":false} )</script></div><script type="text/javascript">new RichFaces.ui.Tab("tree\u002Dform:j_idt21",{"index":0,"leave":null,"togglePanelId":"tree\u002Dform:tree\u002Dtabpanel","switchMode":"client","name":"Blah GmbH","enter":null,"disabled":false} )</script></div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="998210192617713914:-9142017502724223608" autocomplete="off" />
+ </div></span></span></div></div><input type="hidden" name="tree-form:sorting-tree-one__SELECTION_STATE" id="tree-form:sorting-tree-one__SELECTION_STATE" class="rf-tr-sel-inp" value="" /><script type="text/javascript">new RichFaces.ui.Tree("tree\u002Dform:sorting\u002Dtree\u002Done",{"toggleType":"client"} );</script></div></div><script type="text/javascript">new RichFaces.ui.Tab("tree\u002Dform:j_idt21",{"index":0,"leave":null,"togglePanelId":"tree\u002Dform:tree\u002Dtabpanel","switchMode":"client","name":"Blah GmbH","enter":null,"disabled":false} )</script></div><script type="text/javascript">new RichFaces.ui.Tab("tree\u002Dform:j_idt21",{"index":0,"leave":null,"togglePanelId":"tree\u002Dform:tree\u002Dtabpanel","switchMode":"client","name":"Blah GmbH","enter":null,"disabled":false} )</script></div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-5805340602741883884:1908800949269113937" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

The problem here is that I create a dummy root node for the RichFaces root to be displayed and I add the real root via RichFaces `TreeNodeImpl`'s `addChild("real root", ...)`, which contains a space in the key.

The `<a4j:ajax>` code can obviously handle this but not JSF 2's `<f:ajax>` (note the first diff part).

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are illegal in IDs. See also [`UIComponent#setId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setId%28java.lang.String%29) javadoc.

> ### setId
>
> ```
> public abstract void setId(java.lang.String id)
> ```
>
> Set the component identifier of this `UIComponent` (if any). Component identifiers must obey the following syntax restrictions:
>
> - Must not be a zero-length String.
> - First character must be a letter or an underscore ('_').
> - Subsequent characters must be a letter, a digit, an underscore ('_'), or a dash ('-').
>
> Component identifiers must also obey the following semantic restrictions (note that this restriction is NOT enforced by the `setId()` implementation):
>
> - The specified identifier must be unique among all the components (including facets) that are descendents of the nearest ancestor `UIComponent` that is a `NamingContainer`, or within the scope of the entire component tree if there is no such ancestor that is a `NamingContainer`.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> - `id` - The new component identifier, or null to indicate that this `UIComponent` does not have a component identifier
>
> **Throws**:
>
> - `IllegalArgumentException` - if id is not syntactically valid

Seems like that RichFaces is never validating it according the rules for the tree. I would in turn account it as a bug in RichFaces. [Report](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF) it to the RichFaces guys.

Comment: Is this a separate bug in contrast to TreeNodeImpl allowing whitespace in keys as reported at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12245?